# how do I put a Boolean data attribute in a subclass and demonstrate it

Tags: python, pycharm

Right now i'm doing an assignment for class and i'm having problems with the subclass part the question is "Next, write a class named Customer that is a subclass of the Person class. The Customer class should have a data attributes for a customer number, and a Boolean data attribute indicating whether the customer wishes to be on a mailing list. Demonstrate an instance of the Customer class in a simple program."
I have the customer number right but when it asks for a Boolean data attribute I used a Boolean operator but all i'm getting back is True no matter what i put. How else can i put a Boolean attribute

```
'''
customer_class.py: create a class that can a person name, address, age and phone number
and make a program that can make three instances of the class one to hold
personal information and two more to hold a friends information
next make a subclass that display the customer number and if they wish to be on the
mailing list
By: Javon Jamison
3/17/2020
'''


class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name, address, age, phone_number):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.age = age
        self.phone = phone_number

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_address(self):
        return self.address

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

    def get_phone(self):
        return self.phone

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: " + self.name + "\n" + "Address: " + self.address \
    + "\n" + "age: " + self.age + "\n" + "Number: " + self.phone


#person1 = Person('Javon', '123 road', "18", "123-456-7890")
#person2 = Person('Wll', '124 road', "19", "122-455-7893")
#person3 = Person('Bhari', '125 road', "20", "111-222-4444")

#print(person1, "\n", person2, "\n", person3)

class Customer(Person):
    """ subclass of Person"""
    def __init__(self, name, address, age, phone_number, decision):
        super().__init__(name, address, age, phone_number)
        self.number = phone_number
        self.decision = decision

    def get_number(self, phone_number):
        """ get customer number"""
        return self.number == phone_number

    def set_decision(self, decision):
        """ get the customer decision"""
        return self.decision == decision

    def __bool__(self):
        """ determine if they want to be on the list"""
        if self.decision == "y":
            return True
        elif self.decision == "n":
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        """ display the number and if they want to be on mailing list"""
        return self.number




cust1 = Customer('Javon', '123 road', "18", "123-456-7890", "n")

print(cust1)
print(bool(cust1.decision))
```

Comment: As an aside, isn't the naming of `get_number` and `set_decision` misleading? The former does not get the number, and the latter doesn't set the decision attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of overriding the `__bool__` is to use the object directly as a `bool` value like this

```
print(bool(cust1))
```

---

When doing `print(bool(cust1.decision))` you evaluate the boolean value of `cust1.decision` which is a non-empty string `==> True`

Comment: Thank you i was stuck on this for awhile

Comment: @TripleJay You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;)